# Python - while loop inside function not producing consistent results

Tags: python, function, loops

New to coding here. I created a simple program for class that allows the user to get the cost of shipping a flate rate package. The objective was to incorporate functions into the program (Functions in Python is the unit we are in). My instructor said my program works as intended but I could improve it by using a 'while' loop so that if the user enters the wrong selection, it won't kick them from the program suddenly, and will instead prompt them again for imput. I have used 'while' loops before but not within a function and its producing a confusing result.

When I run the program now, exiting by inputting 'X' does halt the program, IF I do not go to a submenu and return to the main menu first. It also no longer displays my thank you message. Additionally, if I DO go to a sub menu and return to the main menu and attempt to exit, the program instead sends me into a sub menu. Last, using the 'while' loop does not produce its intended result, which is to allow the user to make an input error without crashing. Any help is greatly appreciated! Hopefully my question makes sense.

```
def main():
    # Create the menu text
    print('==================================')
    print('Box and Go')
    print('==================================\n')
    print('C: Calculate cost to ship a package')
    print('D: Display shipping cost information')
    print('X: Exit Application\n')
    # Allow the user to select a menu option
    selection = str(input('Enter your menu selection: ').upper())
    while selection.upper() != "X":
        if selection == 'C':
            CalculateCost()
        elif selection == 'D':
            DisplayInfo()
        elif selection == 'X':
            print('\nThanks for choosing Box and Go!')


# Declare the function that shows the shipping rates
def DisplayInfo():
    print('==================================')
    print('SHIPPING COST INFORMATION')
    print('==================================\n')
    print('All packages are flat rate shipping\n')
    print('Flat Rate Envelope\t $6.70')
    print('Small Flat Rate Box\t $7.20')
    print('Medium Flat Rate Box\t $13.65')
    print('Large Flat Rate Box\t $18.90\n')

    # Allow the user to return to the main menu
    selection = str(input('Press enter to return to main menu: ').upper())

    if selection == '':
        main()

# Declare the function that will allow the user to
# find out the total price of each shipping option with tax included
def CalculateCost():
    print('==================================')
    print('COST ESTIMATOR FOR PACKAGES')
    print('==================================\n')

    # The user will select their option here
    selection = str(input('Enter type of package to send:\n(E)nvelope, (S)mall box, (M)edium Box, (L)arge box: ').upper())

    if selection == 'E':
        subtotal = 6.70
    elif selection == 'S':
        subtotal = 7.20
    elif selection == 'M':
        subtotal = 13.65
    elif selection == 'L':
        subtotal = 18.90
    # The program will call the CalcTax function to get the tax, then add that amount
    # to the subtotal, giving them the grand total cost of shipping
    print('\nTotal Shipment Cost: $', format(CalcTax(subtotal) + subtotal, '.2f'), sep=''
          )
    # Allow the user to get back to the main menu(main function)
    main_menu = str(input('\nPress enter to return to main menu'))

    if main_menu == '':
            main()


# Declare the function that will calculate
# tax based on the shipping selection the user made,
# then pass that amount back to the CalculateCost function
# that called it
def CalcTax(number):
    subtotal = number * 0.06
    return subtotal

# Call the main function. The program executes from here
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need

```
main_menu = str(input('\nPress enter to return to main menu'))
if main_menu == '':
    main()
```

Your function should just hand execution to `main()` automatically but if you would like to put something there to make it explicit, you can place a `return` here.

Option 1:

```
# Allow the user to get back to the main menu(main function)
str(input('\nPress enter to return to main menu'))
# program will automatically go back to Main()
```

Option 2:

```
# Allow the user to get back to the main menu(main function)
str(input('\nPress enter to return to main menu'))
return # explicitly say to end this call to your function
```

**UPDATE:**

You also are not asking the user for input every time, but get it once before looping. Here is your code with a couple alterations:

```
def main():
    while True:  # loop forever
        # Create the menu text
        print('==================================')
        print('Box and Go')
        print('==================================\n')
        print('C: Calculate cost to ship a package')
        print('D: Display shipping cost information')
        print('X: Exit Application\n')
        # Allow the user to select a menu option
        selection = str(input('Enter your menu selection: ').upper())
        if selection == 'C':
            CalculateCost()
        elif selection == 'D':
            DisplayInfo()
        elif selection == 'X':
            print('\nThanks for choosing Box and Go!')
            break # end our forever loop


# Declare the function that shows the shipping rates
def DisplayInfo():
    print('==================================')
    print('SHIPPING COST INFORMATION')
    print('==================================\n')
    print('All packages are flat rate shipping\n')
    print('Flat Rate Envelope\t $6.70')
    print('Small Flat Rate Box\t $7.20')
    print('Medium Flat Rate Box\t $13.65')
    print('Large Flat Rate Box\t $18.90\n')

    # Allow the user to return to the main menu
    input('Press enter to return to main menu: ')


# Declare the function that will allow the user to
# find out the total price of each shipping option with tax included
def CalculateCost():
    print('==================================')
    print('COST ESTIMATOR FOR PACKAGES')
    print('==================================\n')

    # The user will select their option here
    selection = str(input('Enter type of package to send:\n(E)nvelope, (S)mall box, (M)edium Box, (L)arge box: ').upper())

    if selection == 'E':
        subtotal = 6.70
    elif selection == 'S':
        subtotal = 7.20
    elif selection == 'M':
        subtotal = 13.65
    elif selection == 'L':
        subtotal = 18.90
    # The program will call the CalcTax function to get the tax, then add that amount
    # to the subtotal, giving them the grand total cost of shipping
    print('\nTotal Shipment Cost: $', format(CalcTax(subtotal) + subtotal, '.2f'), sep='')
    # Allow the user to get back to the main menu(main function)
    input('\nPress enter to return to main menu')
    return


# Declare the function that will calculate
# tax based on the shipping selection the user made,
# then pass that amount back to the CalculateCost function
# that called it
def CalcTax(number):
    subtotal = number * 0.06
    return subtotal

# Call the main function. The program executes from here
main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried both options. Unfortunately they both resulted in not being able to escape the "DisplayInfo" function. I couldn't return to the main menu. I also tried the suggestions above, 

" return str(input('Press enter to return to main menu: ').upper()) "

which produced the same thing.

EDIT: I see your update. I'll give that a try. I haven't tried using "while true" before

Comment: @tromegatron a `while True:` just tells it to loop forever and the only way to exit is to `break` your loop.

Comment: Update 2: That did the trick!

So..... the program wasn't closing because I was calling the function over and over again? So for every time I called the function, I would have to enter 'X' at the main menu for each iteration of the function that was...'open' I guess. The reason I had to use 'return' in the "CalculateCost function was because 'return' closes the iteration of the function I called, and returns the user back to the function that called it. Then, I'm guessing I don't need "return" in the "DisplayInfo" function because there are no values within it that can be returned?

Comment: @tromegatron You can use a `return` even if your function does not return a value. It's unnecessary, but if it helps you think about how you want to "return" execution of your program to the main function it doesn't hurt anything to put it there. The main problem I saw in your script was that `selection = str(input('Enter your menu selection: ').upper())` was outside your loop. So your solution was to keep calling that function to get that to display, but this was resulting in nested `while` loops with each call.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to start learning more about variable scope! Essentially, selection is not a global variable, and when you set its value inside of `DisplayInfo()`, that value isn't actually getting passed back to main(). Instead, considering using `return` to send the user's input back to the function.

Here's your code back with a couple of changes to fix the infinite loop:

```
...
    while selection.upper() != "X":
        if selection == 'C':
             CalculateCost()
        elif selection == 'D':
            selection = DisplayInfo()
        elif selection == 'X':
            print('\nThanks for choosing Box and Go!')


# Declare the function that shows the shipping rates
def DisplayInfo():
    print('==================================')
    print('SHIPPING COST INFORMATION')
    print('==================================\n')
    print('All packages are flat rate shipping\n')
    print('Flat Rate Envelope\t $6.70')
    print('Small Flat Rate Box\t $7.20')
    print('Medium Flat Rate Box\t $13.65')
    print('Large Flat Rate Box\t $18.90\n')

    # Allow the user to return to the main menu
    return str(input('Press enter to return to main menu: ').upper())
```

I'd also recommend spending some time getting to know the call stack (i.e. the depth of functions being called in a program). When you call `main()` inside of `DisplayInfo()`, you're actually running the function *again* via recursion, because it's already running outside of that context. Although the limit of the stack (the proverbial "overflow", as it were) is quite high, theoretically a user who continued to type 'D' would eventually cause your program to error out.